# How to preserve line breaks in column headers with gt tables and LaTeX output?

Tags: r, latex, gt

Is there a way to preserve line breaks in column headers with gt tables and LaTeX output? I have not managed to inject literal LaTeX code yet and other workarounds do not produce the desired effect. In the example below, I would like "(%)" to appear on a new line:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

tbl <- mtcars |> 
  select(1:4) |> 
  head(5) |> 
  gt()

tbl |> 
  cols_label(
    mpg = "mpg\n(%)",
    cyl = md("cyl<br>(%)"),
    disp = "disp\\\\(%)",
    hp = "hp\\(%)"
  )
```

yields
[image]

Only using the `md()` formatter had some effect, although not the desired one:

```r
tbl |> 
  cols_label(
    cyl = md("cyl  \n(%)")
  )
```

[image]

Complete qmd file:

````
---
title: How to preserve line breaks in column headers with LaTeX output?
format: pdf
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| message: false
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

tbl <- mtcars |> 
  select(1:4) |> 
  head(5) |> 
  gt()

tbl |> 
  cols_label(
    mpg = "mpg\n(%)",
    cyl = md("cyl<br>(%)"),
    disp = "disp\\\\(%)",
    hp = "hp\\(%)"
  )
```

```{r}
tbl |> 
  cols_label(
    cyl = md("cyl  \n(%)")
  )
```
````

Comment: Any luck on figuring this out? Seems like it should be a simple thing.

Comment: Nope (but also didn't track this down any further) – I ended up writing a small package for LaTeX output specifically myself: https://github.com/turbanisch/tabularray/